# Questions about gcc pragmas for vectorization

Tags: gcc, vectorization, pragma

There is a very informative youtube video by James Reinders about vectorization.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyZMssi_gZY

In it, he mentions two pragmas – ivdep and omp simd – which force vectorization under different circumstances.

Since Reinders works for Intel I suspect these pragmas are valid for the intel C compiler. Are they also valid for gcc?

In addition, if omp simd is valid for gcc and if I use

```
#pragma omp simd
```

with gcc do I have to use -fopenmp as a commandline option for the compulation?